# filter dropdown appear as object in Active Admin in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Type do
    permit_params :name, :job, version_ids: []
    index do
        id_column
        column :name
        column :job
        column :versions do |type|
            type.versions.collect(&:name).join(', ')
        end
        actions
    end

    form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
        f.inputs do
        f.input :name, as: :string
        f.input :job, as: :string
        f.input :versions, as: :select, input_html: { multiple: true }
        end
        f.actions
    end
end
```

This table has a has_many relation with workers table. The dropdown which shows the worker filter shows the worker object instead of the worker name. How can I get the worker name in the dropdown instead of the worker object.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
f.input :versions, as: :select,
        collection: versions.pluck(:name, :id),
        input_html: { multiple: true }
```